# How to print valid CBOR using serde_cbor?

Tags: rust, cbor

I want to serialize a struct into CBOR and print it out, however I don't know how to validate that the printed value is correct. I used [CBOR.me](http://cbor.me), but every time I place the output in cbor.me it reports `Out of bytes to decode: 753 + 19 > 753` where `753` is the number of bytes of CBOR provided, I get this error regardless of bytes. This happens regardless of whether I use [`serde_cbor::to_vec`](https://pyfisch.github.io/cbor/serde_cbor/ser/fn.to_vec.html), or [`serde_cbor::to_vec_sd`](https://pyfisch.github.io/cbor/serde_cbor/ser/fn.to_vec_sd.html).

```
#![feature(custom_derive, plugin)]
#![plugin(serde_macros)]

extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_cbor;


#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Points {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}


fn main() {
    let points = Points {x: 1, y: 1};
    let cbor = serde_cbor::to_vec(&points);

    for byte in cbor {
        print!("{:x}", byte);
    }

    println!("");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what your output and the correct output would be:

```
a2 61 78 16 17 91
a2 61 78 01 61 79 01
```

Do you see the problem?

```
a2 61 78  1 61 79  1
a2 61 78 01 61 79 01
```

You are printing values out as hexadecimal, but not zero-padding them to 2 characters:

```
print!("{:02x}", byte);
```